# Why is Eobard Thawne not affected by the side effects of creating a flashpoint

Tags: plot-explanation, arrowverse, the-flash

When Barry Allen creates a flashpoint at the end of *The Flash* Season 2, he suffers major memory and power loss as a consequence, but the same doesn't happen with Eobard Thawne.

Seeing the fact that he even created a flashpoint by coming back in time and killing Nora and Harrison Wells, but his memory remains as is and he doesn't even forget about his powers either. Why?

Comment: Just an assumption, but Eobard went to a time where he didn't even exist yet, while Barry returned to a time where he was already born. This might be the reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a wibbly wobbly timey wimey kind of answer, but it's because Eobard actually had no changes to deal with.

Consider this: Barry has run back in time to prevent Eobard killing his mother.  He remembers the death of his mother, his father going to prison and so on.  Eobard however is running back from the 25th century with the intent of killing Barry's mother.  Barry has already lived through these events; Eobard hasn't - he's just been prevented from carrying out his "mission".

This is why Barry's memory starts to change, but nothing happens to Eobard's memory - as far as he's concerned he just failed.

I would point out though that Barry is still superfast in the flashpoint - he's just not operating as the Flash.